# Searching to concatenate columns and in between pick additional amount from another workbook, that shall be incremented

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, increment

I have a file which is modified through VBA.
It is concatenating three columns in the sheet to create a name.

However, another information needs to be concatenated to create the new data.
The data needs to be created by deducing something from data in another workbook.

In a scpecific column, with always the same name (but whose location can change, however in the sheet), the macro needs to look for a specific information. There can be four possibilities.

Once this possibility is identified, once the term is matched from either of these four, the VBA should increment the number in the end of the term in the workbook needs to be incremented.

The structure of is as follows in the first workbook:

- Nip Nup Noupx

For "Noup" there are four cases : Noupx, Noupy, Noupu, Noupa

- The VBA concatentes : NipNupNoupa

(or possibly NipNupNoupx, NipNupNoupu...)

Then the VBA should go in the other workbook, look for either the term "Noupa", "Noupu", "Noupx", "Noupy".

For each of these the specific number comming after "Noupa" (or the other) should be identified and should increment it by adding "+1".

Thus the result would be:

- Noupa002 (resulting from the identification of Noupa001)
- Noupu034 (resulting from the identificiation of Noupu033)

For the time being, I have the following VBA code, I do not know how to look for data in another workbook and increment it.

```
Sub TralaNome()

    Const q = """"

    ' get source data table from sheet 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

   ' check if data exists
        If .Rows.Count < 2 Or .Columns.Count < 2 Then
            MsgBox "No data table"
            Exit Sub
        End If

   ' retrieve headers name and column numbers dictionary
        Dim headers As Dictionary
        Set headers = New Dictionary
        Dim headCell
        For Each headCell In .Rows(1).Cells
            headers(headCell.Value) = headers.Count + 1
        Next

   ' check mandatory headers

        For Each headCell In Array(("Costumer", "ID", "Zone“,  "Product Quali", "Spec A", "Spec B", "Spec_C", "Spec_D", "Spec_1",  " Spec_2", " Spec_3", " Spec_4", " Spec_5", " Spec_6", " Spec_7", "Chiavetta", "Tipo_di _prodotto",  "Unicorno_Cioccolato", “cacao tree“)
            If Not headers.Exists(headCell) Then
                MsgBox "Header '" & headCell & "' doesn't exists"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        Dim data

 ' retrieve table data
        data = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value
    End With

   ' process each row in table data
    Dim result As Dictionary
    Set result = New Dictionary
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
                    MsgBox "Empty row"
                    Exit For
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & "ID " & data(i, headers("ID ")) & _
                        q & " Tipo_di _prodotto " & data(i, headers("Tipo_di _prodotto")) & _
                        q & " cacao tree " & data(i, headers("Nupu")) & _
                        q
        End Select

    Next

    ' output result data to sheet 2
    If result.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No result data for output"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(result.Count).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(result.Items())
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"


End Sub
```

The columns are grouped through this macro, but I need to now look in the other worksheet, increment the various Noupu, Noupy etc etc etc...

I think that a VBA of that sort should be used to add an incremented value :

```
Function GetLastRowWithData(WorksSheetNoupa As Worksheet, Optional NoupaLastCol As Long) As Long
    Dim lCol, lRow, lMaxRow As Long
    If NoupaLastCol = 0 Then
        NoupaLastCol = wsSheet.Columns.Count
    End If
    lMaxRow = 0
    For lCol = NoupaLastCol To 1 Step -1
        lRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, lCol).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow > lMaxRow Then
            lMaxRow = lRow
        End If
    Next
    GetLastRowWithData = lMaxRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry, this probably should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation as yet).
However even without checking through your code in detail, I'm seeing an `exit for` in the middle of a for loop without an `If` to avoid it in certain conditions. Presumably this means that whatever's written below that line in the loop, never gets done - nor is the loop any good for anything but the first instance. (it's the loop that's annotated `'process each row in table data`)

Have you tried running this step by step? (go into the VBEditor with a test dataset open, and hit F8 or the 'step into' button in debug toolbar )

Comment: I have tried. I formatted in not properly in stack overflow. My main and horrible issue in the aggregation of multiple different and complex actions that I need to undertake in a groupe way altogether in VBA. This is complex. The proper code closes the loop. Thank you for pointing that out. I corrected that. However, in my actual code, besides the other point in my qusetion I get a "compile error" "User defined type not defined"

Comment: I managed to solve the "user defined type not defined" compile error. However, now, when running the macro, I keep having systemiatically the name of one of my column as a message followed by "does not exist". Despite even earsing this option as the list of headers to search for, I still get this message.

Comment: Using that F8 method, at which line does this error occur?